# ESRI Web Application Developer Certification

Tags: arcgis-platform, certification

Does anyone know if there are any sample questions available for the ESRI Web Application Developer Certification exam?

---

ESRI has released 3 sample questions for this test:

http://downloads2.esri.com/campus/downloads/certification/samplequestions/EWDA10_Sample_Questions.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Web Application Developer is still in development
http://training.esri.com/certification/

The **ArcGIS Desktop** one is re offered worldwide through Pearson VUE, Esri's global testing partner. The computer-based exams consist of 90-95 multiple-choice questions and take approximately two hours to complete. Currently, they are offered in English only

see previous post
[Format and value of Esri Technical Certification?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4883/questions-on-esri-technical-certification)

Comment: The Web Application Developer certification is out of beta and they are currently accepting registrations.

Answer (score 1):

Not at the time of me writing this.
Although I know some ppl that took the web app developer associate in the Beta stage, and the mentioned that it was pretty full on.

Comment: Ill update this if I can find some sample Qs from the Beta.

Answer (score 1):

[Cert Camp](http://blogs.esri.com/Support/blogs/esritrainingmatters/archive/2011/02/01/spring-training-camp-skills-review-courses-for-esri-technical-certification.aspx) is not actually the questions, but may be a step toward passing exams.

Comment: That definitely looks helpful, I just wish they were doing one for the Web Application Developer certification.